# MAGENTO: Server Down when access Media Storage

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, server-setup

Basically whenever I try to access Media Storage. Usually by going to `CMS->Pages->click on any page from the list->Content->Insert Image->Storage Root.`
The moment I click on Storage Root the server image tumbnails start to load but the server load raises highly and server restarts. Site is down for good 2-3 minutes.

I have approximately 100 picture that are stored in Storage Root and only about 30% of thumbnails load before the server crashes.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: is it some php process high cpu usage or iowait?

Comment: Seems as a some php process causes high CPU usage. To to the point the server restarts.

Comment: I think its due to having 100 image thumbnails trying to load. and only about 30% load before server crashes

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$count_images = 0;
$urls = "";

foreach($collection as $product)
{
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $_gallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    $count_images += count($_gallery);

    foreach($_gallery as $image)
    {
        $image_path = realpath('media/catalog/product/'.$image->getFile());
        echo $image_path.' ->'.Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image_path)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->resize(200,null)."\n";
    }
}

echo "$count_images thumbnail generated";
```

Normally it means the thumbnails have not been generated for some of the Images you're loading up and most likely the server becomes overloaded and fails to finish the request.  I'm guessing the server you are on is not very high end? Magento usually doesn't work very well on shared/budget hosting.  You can also try the `Flush Catalog Images Cache   Pregenerated product images files.` in the Magento Admin under System > Cache.  NOTE This may overload your server again.

With the script above you may have some more fine grained control of when/what is failing and possibly starting back over at the point the catalog image generation fails normally.

I would also look into `htop` or even `top` command and note if PHP is taking longer than any default timeouts in your `php.ini` or `.htaccess` files causing the image generation to fail.  Upping the PHP timeouts can sometimes help. NOTE the script has a execution time of -1 infinite, and -1 on memory limit.

You can try to generate the Image thumbnails via the script above.  Save it as `imagegeneration.php` in the root of your store, SSH in and run `php imagegeneration.php`

Comment: I've used three browsers to open Media Storage. Chrome: Only 10 first images load (then server restarts). FireFox 20-30 images load ( then server restarts). Internet Explorer (60 images load and server load spikes but never restarts). When using IE the website does NOT go down for several minutes, its slow for a one minute then all good.

Comment: The most thumbnail I was able to load is using IE, about 60 images out of 100. I checked the CPU usage, basically by the time 60th image is loaded the CPU is high that it stops processing of the 40 images. But server is not restarting which is good.

Comment: Different Browsers may not have much affect as the issue is with the Server itself, What are the specifications of the server you're hosting on?

Comment: 2x 3.0GHz CPU......2GB DDR3 RAM ........40GB Disk Space... its a vps

Comment: @Icon yea, VPS are notoriously buggy with Magento. Since you're sharing hardware thats sliced up amongst others, theres no way to know if someone else is eating up resources. I'd highly recommend moving to a dedicated server. Amazon or Rackspace cloud is a great alternative that is still budget friendly.

Comment: Really appreciate advice I will look into them.

Answer (score 1):

if you open linux `top` you can see some processes using too much cpu,
you can quickly check whats inside this process, also check error log.

for example:

`strace -p PID` or   `lsof -p PID`

check if you have enough swap space. usually VPS will restart because of insufficient memory.

iim sure you have incorrect config, thats why memory management is wrong.

Comment: I am checking the Error log and the moment I try to open the Media Folder  the server load rises and error log shows: "stopped because of load 51.31" I think 51 is the critical load in my case when server restarts.

Comment: Swap space is at the minimum which is great. However Memory is filled at 45%

Answer (score 0):

This post receives some great tips from other posters!
However, I found an answer, even though it's not written by me, the website I will include provides great explanation and instruction how to edit certain element of code so **thumbnails** don't load-up every time when you open Media Storage. Basically those of us who have alot of images stored in Media Storage, unless the server is capable of handing it all, its good to implement small code change which will prevent the server from loading thumbnails over and over again, hitting peak CPU usage, causing server drops.
Thanks to this team for detailed instructions:

```
https://www.ctidigital.com/blog/fixing-magento-improving-performance-of-the-wysiwyg-editor/
```

Its too much information to post on StackOverflow and the issue is best described on the site in much greater detail. So please follow the link and make respective adjustment.

Comment: This does not solve the issue of loading 100's of thumbnails it just does it a bit quicker

Comment: Well, server no longer overloads after implementing the fix, images load in seconds without server crashes. So I consider it a fix.

Comment: If your loading files over HTTPS though it's still pretty slow, my comment is more, yes it takes the strain off the server producing thumbnails on the fly and is definitely quicker!, but it does not change the fact that if you have hundreds or thousands of images, each time the gallery is opened it needs to load 500+ thumbnails for example that's still going to be slow.